# Select Max Date for all combinations

Tags: sql

Having a table made of ~10 columns, how can I select all combinations of those columns where the timestamp is the latest one?

```
Country City    Street  ... Timestamp
Poland  Warsaw  OldSt   ... 5/25/2018
Poland  Warsaw  NewSt   ... 6/14/2018
Germany Berlin  OldSt   ... 5/30/2018
Germany Berlin  NewSt   ... 6/14/2018
France  Paris   SomeSt  ... 6/14/2018
```

Would get me

```
Country City    Street  ... Timestamp
Poland  Warsaw  NewSt   ... 6/14/2018
Germany Berlin  NewSt   ... 6/14/2018
France  Paris   SomeSt  ... 6/14/2018
```

I believe there are many approaches to this issue. What is the most performant one, though?

The DDL of the table:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table SDATA
(
  SID bigint unsigned auto_increment
    primary key,
  FG                     varchar(100) charset utf8 default ''        not null,
  COUNTRY                varchar(100) charset utf8 default ''        not null,
  CITY                   varchar(100) charset utf8 default 'unknown' not null,
  F_DATE                 date default '0000-00-00'                   not null,
  INTERVAL_START         datetime default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'      not null,
  INTERVAL_DURATION      bigint unsigned default '0'                 not null,
  VOLUME                 decimal(10, 5) default '0.00000'            not null,
  SNAPSHOT_DATE          datetime default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'      not null,
  VERSION                date                                        null,
)
  ;

create index idx_SCD_IS_SD_FGN
  on SDATA (INTERVAL_START, SNAPSHOT_DATE, FG);
```

Whilst the reply from Gordon Linoff works, it runs for 33s for one week worth of data. Any way to speed it up?

Comment: the sintax for mysql can vary from postgresql

Comment: You seem to want all combinations of two specific columns, not all columns

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 4):

One method that works well across databases is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.country = t.country and t2.city = t.city
                    );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(country, city, timestamp)`.

Comment: Sample data is somewhat unclear (6/14/2018 is common to all those "maximum dates") so - maybe the whole `WHERE` clause in the correlated subquery is unnecessary ... I'm not saying that your query is wrong - on the contrary!

Comment: Works flawlessly - the running time is 33s for one week worth of data. I added the DDL to the question. Any tips on improving the performance?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *
from table
where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table)
```

edit

```
select *
from table a
where a.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from table b where a.Country = b.country)
```

edit with CTE

```
with CTE
as
(
    select COUNTRY, CITY, max(INTERVAL_START) as date from SDATA group by 
    COUNTRY, CITY
)
select a.* from SDATA as a
inner join CTE as b on a.COUNTRY = b.COUNTRY and a.CITY = b.CITY and a.INTERVAL_START = date
```

Comment: doesn't work too... with that query you get the "total max", not the relative max for each country